# ¿como serian estas funciones en phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Holaaaa...bueno, el profe de base de datos nos dejo una tarea de base de datos de crear unas funciones, pero hay un problema conmigo y con otros estudiantes, resulta que el profe ya sabe que algunos, incluyendome, no pudimos descargar postgresql por x razón, pero a el le valio y pues explico toda la clase con la sintaxis de postgresql, al final pues le pregunte en nombre de todos si se podia realizar la tarea en el editor de sql de xampp, y pues dijo que si, pero cuando nos compartio el archivo con las funciones que hay que crear, lo mando con la sintaxis de postgrsql -.-, bueno, el caso es que de la sintaxis del editor de xampp yo no se nada por q no nos lo ha explicado, y pues queria pedirles una ayudita en esto

Como (con la sintaxis del editor de xampp) se crean estas funciones?

```
create or replace function funcMaxPopu()
returns integer as
$BODY$
declare
insal integer;
begin
select max(population) into insal from city;

end;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

y esta

```
create or replace function func_mayor_pob_ciu_pais(p_pais varchar)
returns varchar as
$body$
declare
  vaName  varchar; 
  vaPop   integer;
begin
 select c.name ciudad, max(c.population) poblacion into vaName, vaPop
 from  city c, country t
 where c.countrycode = t.code
 and   lower(t.name) = p_pais
 group by c.name
 order by poblacion desc
 limit 1;  
return vaname; 
end;
$body$ language 'plpgsql'
```

Gracias de antemano :3

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Xampp es un paquete de instalacion que instala varias cosas.. entre ellas, mysql, y supongo tu pregunta es como hacer esas funciones en mysql... no? ahora... no importa que esten en postgress, lo que tenes que entender es que hacen, y reescribirlas en mysql....

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: phpMyAdmin es una interfaz para trabajar sobre el MySQL/MariaDB que viene ahí. La forma en la que esa BD crea funciones va a diferir de lo que PostgreSQL pide al escribir plpgsql por detalles de sintaxis. La recomendación es que descargues postgresql y uses pgAdmin, en vez de hacer un frankestein que te va a hacer perder tiempo en lo que no es. Mejor reformula la pregunta y cuéntanos cuál es la X razón para no descargar postgresql y te ayudamos a resolverla :)

Comment: Como bien dice @Alfabravo, si estás aprendiendo PostgreSQL usa las herramientas de PostgreSQL. Si no, es como estar aprendiendo a ser peluquero y usar un cuchillo para cortar el pelo. pgAdmin es gratis, y [hay versiones para los sistemas operativos más usados](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/), ¿cuál es el problema con él?